# How to make jquery script easier to read?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I was looking at a script used by a website and the code is packed, with no indentations or structure(In actuality every web-site I went to had this kind of code structure.). I was trying to learn jquery, so I thought I should look at other people codes using google dev tools. How to make this [code](https://reef.finance/_nuxt/aa96422.js) easier to read ?

Comment: In Developer Tools Sources tab, click on the `{}` tool to reformat it.

Comment: @DanO That code isn't obfuscated. It's just minified.

Comment: But it still won't be understandable, because all the variable names have been removed.

Comment: Don't try to learn from minified production code. Find examples in github.

Comment: In PHPStorm Ctrl+Alt+(Shift)+L https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your suggestion. I will search github for better examples.

Comment: @Barmar one of the utilities linked in that thread claims to try to substitute human-meaningful variable names for minified names.  (I agree though, this is not the best way to learn how to use jQuery.)

Comment: @DanO The explanation says that it does that by searching github for the code. Proprietary code is probably not in public repos.

Comment: @DanO can you also give me suggestions on how I should learn JQuery. Is it same as Barmar, search through github examples ?